# Nested relative imports don't seem to work

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

### Description

I have a package structure where various modules need to obtain information from different ones and therefore I use relative imports. It happens that those relative imports are nested in some way.
I'll just present you the package structure I have:

```
.
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── sub1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mod1.py
│   └── sub2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── mod1.py
│       └── sub1
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── mod1.py
└── main.py
```

The files contain the following statements:

#### main.py:

```
print __name__
import core.sub2.mod1
```

#### core/sub2/mod1.py

```
print __name__
import sub1.mod1
```

#### core/sub2/sub1/mod1.py

```
print __name__
from ...sub1 import mod1
```

#### core/sub1/mod1.py

```
print __name__
from ..sub2 import mod1
```

#### Visualization

A visualization of the imports:

[image: Visualization]

### Problem

When I run `python main.py` I get the following error (I substituted the absolute file paths with `./<path-to-file>`):

```
__main__
core.sub2.mod1
core.sub2.sub1.mod1
core.sub1.mod1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import core.sub2.mod1
  File "./core/sub2/mod1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sub1.mod1
  File "./core/sub2/sub1/mod1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ...sub1 import mod1
  File "./core/sub1/mod1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..sub2 import mod1
ImportError: cannot import name mod1
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) I learned that python uses the `__name__` attribute of a module to resolve its location within the package. So I printed all the names of the modules and they seem to be alright! Why do I get this `ImportError` then? And how can I make all the imports work?

Comment: Did you try adding `__init__.py` to your root location?

Comment: This won't help because I'm not issuing any import above `core`'s level. `core` is a package and `main.py` just uses this package.

Comment: You have an import cycle. Circular imports tend to fail when you're using `from module import name` syntax, since the `name` might not be defined yet in `module` if it's not yet fully loaded. Later versions of Python 3 have improved this a little bit, but it's still quite harry. The general recommendation is to avoid circular imports whenever you can, and use plain old absolute imports (`import foo.bar.baz`, no `from`, no `as`) whenever you can't. Some programmers will go further and suggest that circular imports suggest bad module design (that things are too closely coupled across packages).

Comment: @Blckknght Your comment made me think about my package structure and I realized that the structure actually wasn't optimal and so eventually I could remove the import cycle by restructuring it. I guess what you said holds under almost all circumstances, there's always the possibility to structure a package without import cycles (and I feel that this often is a more intuitive approach to it).

Answer (score 0):

As @Blckknght pointed out, you have an import cycle. you can eliminate this annoying cycle by reorganizing your code.

But if you don't have to invoke `core.sub2.mod1` immediately when importing `core.sub1.mod1`, there is a simple way to fix it.

You can import `core.sub2` and invoke `core.sub2.mod1` later.

#### core/sub1/mod1.py

```
print __name__
from .. import sub2
def foo():
    t = sub2.mod1
```

Comment: This won't work. How do you access `sub2.mod1`? You have to make it available via `sub2.__init__`: `import mod1`. And the moment you do `from .. import sub2` `sub.__init__` will be evaluated and you'll end up in an import cycle again.

Comment: @a_guest You didn't show `sub2/__init__.py` content at first so that I assumed this file is blank. If you remove `import mod1` from `sub2._init__`, this will work.